# C# how horizontal scroll using button in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

how horizontal scroll using button in datagridview?

```
dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 30;
```

and,how to back scroll in datagridview?

Comment: isn't this working for you? To Scroll back `dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset - 30;` use `minus`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your questions correctly you are asking how to scroll a datagridview sideways when pressing a button?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
public void Right(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 30;
}



public void Left(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dotaz2AdvancedDataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset - 30;
}
```

Then you just need to assign these events to the buttons you would like to use